# Strange Processor Behavior

Tags: cpufreq, intel-cpu

So now my processor boots locked at 800mhz every boot, and every wake-from-sleep. This occurs in both Windows and Linux. For Windows, I throttlestop and check/uncheck BD prochot and thermal prochot and it unsticks. For Ubuntu, I run

```
sudo wrmsr 0x1FC 2c005d
```

and it also unsticks. Pretty annoying to have to run this every boot and every wake from sleep, and deal with ridiculous sluggishness up until the command executes.

Any tips for msr-tools or firmware fixes? I might stoop to battery unplugging, but it's just so many screws to unscrew and rescrew when all I want is to flip a couple bits somewhere deep in the firmware.

I probably brought this on either by installing XTU and undervolting, and/or by updating Windows. The latest Windows update broke a favorite game, and likely has some funky interplay with Intel XTU. I've run XTU and throttlestop and undervolt and MSIAfterburner in the past, stably, with no issues like this. I don't understand why thermal throttling flag re-engages upon boot and upon wake from sleep. Understanding this mystery probably goes a long way toward solving the problem. I wouldn't be sure it's re-engaging, except that when I do the check/uncheck BD prochot in Throttlestop in Windows, XTU goes from saying Thermal Throttling: Yes to Thermal Throttling: No, and the processor unsticks from 800mhz. In Ubuntu, I can't be sure I'm actually canceling the Thermal Throttling flag, but I do know I'm unsticking the processor throttling with the msr command.

Comment: Please provide the CPU model by clicking [edit].

Answer (score 0):

Went with battery disconnect, issue didn't persist through reboot.